# Aligning group plot titles horizontally

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

I'm trying to figure out why my plot titles are not horizontally aligned. I tried several sources but could not find an option to control title alignment. Below image is what I get. As you can see Kingsbury and Northcote are not on the same level.

[image: Group plot with misaligned titles]

This is my latex code

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\begin{filecontents*}{cossim.csv}
SAE,Kingsbury large,Kingsbury very small,Northcote large,Northcote very small
0.01,0.999968942313215,0.999999495420309,0.99996093797435,0.999999519021115
0.02,0.999871138637117,0.999998360123856,0.999845179891564,0.999997875670629
0.03,0.999719561898977,0.999995711779553,0.999650464340874,0.999995691207506
0.04,0.999501451940394,0.999992937485087,0.999380356722573,0.999991943604557
0.05,0.999209403163912,0.99998965609147,0.999026294939076,0.999988236057768
0.06,0.998864174035993,0.999986379082264,0.998602080363523,0.999982264001694
0.07,0.998482447668418,0.999979693720795,0.998095945546854,0.999975630444692
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    axis background/.style={fill=mygrey},
    tick style=mygrey2,
    tick label style=mygrey2,
    grid=both,
    ytick pos=left,
    tick style={
        major grid style={style=white,line width=1pt},
        minor grid style=mygrey3,
        tick align=outside,
    },
    commonstyle/.style={
        draw=white,
        mark=*,
    },
    midystyle/.style = {
        yticklabels={,,},
        ytick style={draw=none},
        ylabel = {},
    },
    midxstyle/.style = {
        xtick style={draw=none},
        xlabel = {},
    },
    cossimstyle/.style = {
        ymin = 0.998,
    },
}

\definecolor{mygrey}{RGB}{229,229,229}
\definecolor{mygrey2}{RGB}{127,127,127}
\definecolor{mygrey3}{RGB}{240,240,240}
\definecolor{cLarge}{RGB}{31,120,180}
\definecolor{cVerySmall}{RGB}{253,191,111}

\begin{tikzpicture}%

    \begin{groupplot}[%
        group style={%
            group name=QuantileError,%
            group size= 2 by 1,%
            horizontal sep = 0.1cm,
        },%
        width=0.3\textwidth,
        height=0.4\textwidth,
        legend cell align={left}, %
        legend style={draw=white, fill=mygrey3},%
        every axis label/.style={font=\small},%
        ticklabel style = {font=\tiny},%
        yticklabel style={/pgf/number                           
            format/.cd,fixed,precision=4,zerofill,/tikz/.cd},%
        x tick label style={rotate=90, anchor=east},
        scaled x ticks=false,
        xticklabel style={/pgf/number                           
            format/.cd,fixed,precision=2,zerofill,/tikz/.cd},
        ]%

        %%%%% ROW1 Start %%%%%
        \nextgroupplot[%
            commonstyle,
            midxstyle,
            cossimstyle,
            legend to name=mainplot,%
            legend style={legend columns=4},%
            ylabel={Cosine similarity},% 
            title=Kingsbury,
        ]%
        \addplot[color=cLarge] table [x={SAE}, y={Kingsbury large}, col     
            sep=comma]{cossim.csv};%
        \addplot[color=cVerySmall] table [x={SAE}, y={Kingsbury very small}, 
        col sep=comma]{cossim.csv};%

        \nextgroupplot[%
            commonstyle,
            midystyle,
            midxstyle,
            cossimstyle,
            title={Northcote},
        ]%
        \addplot[color=cLarge] table [x={SAE}, y={Northcote large}, col  
            sep=comma]{cossim.csv};%
        \addplot[color=cVerySmall] table [x={SAE}, y={Northcote very small},    
            col sep=comma]{cossim.csv};%
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: because the "Northop" hasnt leter "y". if you will add `\vphantom{y}` to it, words will become aligned as you like to have. however, you can define `title` style in which you add `text depth=0.5ex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, change your `groupplot` settings to:

```
\begin{groupplot}[%
    group style={%
        group name=QuantileError,%
        group size= 2 by 1,%
        horizontal sep = 0.1cm,
    },%
    width=0.3\textwidth,
    height=0.4\textwidth,
    legend cell align={left}, %
    legend style={draw=white, fill=mygrey3},%
    every axis label/.style={font=\small},%
    ticklabel style = {font=\tiny},%
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number
        format/.cd,fixed,precision=4,zerofill,/tikz/.cd},%
    x tick label style={rotate=90, anchor=east},
    scaled x ticks=false,
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number
        format/.cd,fixed,precision=2,zerofill,/tikz/.cd},
    title style = {text depth=0.5ex}                       % <--- added
   ]%
```

and you will get desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can add  `title style={text depth = 0pt}` to your `\nextgroupplot[...]` options to both of the plots and you will have everything aligned horizontally.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\begin{filecontents*}{cossim.csv}
SAE,Kingsbury large,Kingsbury very small,Northcote large,Northcote very small
0.01,0.999968942313215,0.999999495420309,0.99996093797435,0.999999519021115
0.02,0.999871138637117,0.999998360123856,0.999845179891564,0.999997875670629
0.03,0.999719561898977,0.999995711779553,0.999650464340874,0.999995691207506
0.04,0.999501451940394,0.999992937485087,0.999380356722573,0.999991943604557
0.05,0.999209403163912,0.99998965609147,0.999026294939076,0.999988236057768
0.06,0.998864174035993,0.999986379082264,0.998602080363523,0.999982264001694
0.07,0.998482447668418,0.999979693720795,0.998095945546854,0.999975630444692
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    axis background/.style={fill=mygrey},
    tick style=mygrey2,
    tick label style=mygrey2,
    grid=both,
    ytick pos=left,
    tick style={
        major grid style={style=white,line width=1pt},
        minor grid style=mygrey3,
        tick align=outside,
    },
    commonstyle/.style={
        draw=white,
        mark=*,
    },
    midystyle/.style = {
        yticklabels={,,},
        ytick style={draw=none},
        ylabel = {},
    },
    midxstyle/.style = {
        xtick style={draw=none},
        xlabel = {},
    },
    cossimstyle/.style = {
        ymin = 0.998,
    },
}

\definecolor{mygrey}{RGB}{229,229,229}
\definecolor{mygrey2}{RGB}{127,127,127}
\definecolor{mygrey3}{RGB}{240,240,240}
\definecolor{cLarge}{RGB}{31,120,180}
\definecolor{cVerySmall}{RGB}{253,191,111}

\begin{tikzpicture}%

    \begin{groupplot}[%
        group style={%
            group name=QuantileError,%
            group size= 2 by 1,%
            horizontal sep = 0.1cm,
        },%
        width=0.3\textwidth,
        height=0.4\textwidth,
        legend cell align={left}, %
        legend style={draw=white, fill=mygrey3},%
        every axis label/.style={font=\small},%
        ticklabel style = {font=\tiny},%
        yticklabel style={/pgf/number                           
            format/.cd,fixed,precision=4,zerofill,/tikz/.cd},%
        x tick label style={rotate=90, anchor=east},
        scaled x ticks=false,
        xticklabel style={/pgf/number                           
            format/.cd,fixed,precision=2,zerofill,/tikz/.cd},
        ]%

        %%%%% ROW1 Start %%%%%
        \nextgroupplot[%
            commonstyle,
            midxstyle,
            cossimstyle,
            legend to name=mainplot,%
            legend style={legend columns=4},%
            ylabel={Cosine similarity},% 
            title style={text depth = 0pt},  % NEED THIS!
            title=Kingsbury,
        ]%
        \addplot[color=cLarge] table [x={SAE}, y={Kingsbury large}, col     
            sep=comma]{cossim.csv};%
        \addplot[color=cVerySmall] table [x={SAE}, y={Kingsbury very small}, 
        col sep=comma]{cossim.csv};%

        \nextgroupplot[%
            commonstyle,
            midystyle,
            midxstyle,
            cossimstyle,
            title style={text depth = 0pt}, % NEED THIS!
            title={Northcote},
        ]%
        \addplot[color=cLarge] table [x={SAE}, y={Northcote large}, col  
            sep=comma]{cossim.csv};%
        \addplot[color=cVerySmall] table [x={SAE}, y={Northcote very small},    
            col sep=comma]{cossim.csv};%
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to previous two answers is anchoring the title text to top (north) and adding some distance between the titles and the plots with `title style={anchor=north, yshift=2ex}`.

The reason for the problem is explained in Zarko's comment. That is why the title with "g" and "y" is higher than the other one. My solution is aligning the title text to top of the letters rather than to the bottom. But this cause the plot to overlap with the title. So we have to add some distance between them with yshift.

```
\begin{groupplot}[%
    group style={%
        group name=QuantileError,%
        group size= 2 by 1,%
        horizontal sep = 0.1cm,
    },%
    width=0.3\textwidth,
    height=0.4\textwidth,
    legend cell align={left}, %
    legend style={draw=white, fill=mygrey3},%
    every axis label/.style={font=\small},%
    ticklabel style = {font=\tiny},%
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number
        format/.cd,fixed,precision=4,zerofill,/tikz/.cd},%
    x tick label style={rotate=90, anchor=east},
    scaled x ticks=false,
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number
        format/.cd,fixed,precision=2,zerofill,/tikz/.cd},
    title style={anchor=north, yshift=2ex}               % <--- FIX
   ]%
```